# How to display 4 different pieces of text after certain list-items and start over

Tags: jquery

I would like to define about 4 different quotes (New text 1, New text 2, New text 3 and New text 4) and have them shown within listitems with a certain class (training). I would like to preserve a load order of 1,2,3 and 4 and then start over again.

I've tried to use css and write stuff like:

```
    .training:nth-child(1) p::after {content: " New text 1";}
    .training:nth-child(2) p::after {content: " New text 2";}
    .training:nth-child(3) p::after {content: " New text 3";}
    .training:nth-child(4) p::after {content: " New text 4";}
```

But this didn't work because beneath the list I call a piece of jQuery that actually adds an attribute to the containing div.

I've tried to add an empty span and use jQuery and do something like:

```
    <script>
    $(function() {
        var addition = new Array(" New text 1", " New text 2", " New text 3", " New text 4"),
        randno = addition[Math.floor( Math.random() * addition.length )];
        $('.training span').text(randno);
    });
    </script>
```

This is getting close but it delivers the same text in every list item, where I need them to be the full array in consecutive order (1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,etc).

Does anyone know how to do this?

This is the existing code:

```
    <li class="tournament"><p>Existing variable text.</p></li>
    <li class="training"><p>Existing variable text.</p></li>
    <li class="training"><p>Existing variable text.</p></li>
    <li class="tournament"><p>Existing variable text.</p></li>
    <li class="training"><p>Existing variable text.</p></li>
    <li class="tournament"><p>Existing variable text.</p></li>
    <li class="training"><p>Existing variable text.</p></li>
    <li class="training"><p>Existing variable text.</p></li>
    <li class="tournament"><p>Existing variable text.</p></li>
    <li class="training"><p>Existing variable text.</p></li>
```

This is what needs to be shown:

```
    <li class="tournament"><p>Existing variable text.</p></li>
    <li class="training"><p>Existing variable text. New text 1</p></li>
    <li class="training"><p>Existing variable text. New text 2</p></li>
    <li class="tournament"><p>Existing variable text.</p></li>
    <li class="training"><p>Existing variable text. New text 3</p></li>
    <li class="tournament"><p>Existing variable text.</p></li>
    <li class="training"><p>Existing variable text. New text 4</p></li>
    <li class="training"><p>Existing variable text. New text 1</p></li>
    <li class="tournament"><p>Existing variable text.</p></li>
    <li class="training"><p>Existing variable text. New text 2</p></li>
    etc.
```

Does anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$(function() {
  var addition = new Array(" New text 1", " New text 2", " New text 3", " New text 4")
  $('.training span').text(function() {
    var randno = addition[Math.floor(Math.random() * addition.length)];
    return randno;
  });
});
```

Please not that your html did not contain any `<span>` so I've added them to your `li.training`

**Working example**

```js
$(function() {
  var addition = new Array(" New text 1", " New text 2", " New text 3", " New text 4")
  $('.training span').text(function() {
    var randno = addition[Math.floor(Math.random() * addition.length)];
    return randno;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="tournament">
  <p>Existing variable text.</p>
</li>
<li class="training">
  <p>Existing variable text.<span></span></p>
</li>
<li class="training">
  <p>Existing variable text.<span></span></p>
</li>
<li class="tournament">
  <p>Existing variable text.</p>
</li>
<li class="training">
  <p>Existing variable text.<span></span></p>
</li>
<li class="tournament">
  <p>Existing variable text.</p>
</li>
<li class="training">
  <p>Existing variable text.<span></span></p>
</li>
<li class="training">
  <p>Existing variable text.<span></span></p>
</li>
<li class="tournament">
  <p>Existing variable text.</p>
</li>
<li class="training">
  <p>Existing variable text.</p>
</li>
```

**IF you want to override the existing text use this**

```
$(function() {
  var addition = new Array(" New text 1", " New text 2", " New text 3", " New text 4")
  $('.training').text(function(i, x) {
    var randno = addition[Math.floor(Math.random() * addition.length)];
    return x + randno;
  });
});
```

```js
$(function() {
  var addition = new Array(" New text 1", " New text 2", " New text 3", " New text 4")
  var t = 0;
  $('.training').text(function(i, x) {
    var randno = addition[t];
    t = (t == 3 ? 0 : (t + 1));
    return x + randno;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="tournament">
    <p>Existing variable text.</p>
  </li>
  <li class="training">
    <p>Existing variable text.</p>
  </li>
  <li class="training">
    <p>Existing variable text.</p>
  </li>
  <li class="tournament">
    <p>Existing variable text.</p>
  </li>
  <li class="training">
    <p>Existing variable text.</p>
  </li>
  <li class="tournament">
    <p>Existing variable text.</p>
  </li>
  <li class="training">
    <p>Existing variable text.</p>
  </li>
  <li class="training">
    <p>Existing variable text.</p>
  </li>
  <li class="tournament">
    <p>Existing variable text.</p>
  </li>
  <li class="training">
    <p>Existing variable text.</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hey great @Carsten. Again almost there... is there a way to nót have it randomized but in the same consecutive order: 1,2,3,4, 1,2,3,4, 1,2,3,4, etc

Comment: @KestonPollard open the last example and look at the js part there

Comment: No problem @KestonPollard